# How can I get Intent of my custom object in array?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

Here's what inside Player.class

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by pietsteph on 15/09/17.
 */

public class Player implements Parcelable{
String name;
int score;


protected Player(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    score = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeInt(score);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Creator<Player>() {
    @Override
    public Player createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Player(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Player[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Player[size];
    }
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public Player(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = 0;
}
```

}

In the MainActivity.class, I make my custom object as an array with size = 2 (2 player) and put it in intent.

```
Player players[] = new Player[2];
players[0] = new Player(name1);
players[1] = new Player(name2);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TurnActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PLAYER_KEY, players);
startActivity(intent);
```

Want to get my intent in TurnActivity.class, tried getParcelableExtra.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Player players[] = intent.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.PLAYER_KEY);
```

But it gave me an error

```
Error:(28, 59) error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)inferred: INT#1
upper bound(s): Player[],Parcelable
where INT#1 is an intersection type:
INT#1 extends Player[],Parcelable
```

Even tried getParcelableArrayExtra and gave me a red line says Incompatible type.

Comment: Array indexing starts from "0" in Java

Comment: I don't think that's the main problem. The main issue is how to get intent of my custom object in array.

Comment: Please try using `getParcelableArrayExtra()` instead of `getParcelableExtra()`.

Comment: Please show Player class

Comment: @Andremoniy OP can;t get his code to compile. The error is a compiler error, not a runtime Exception. If he does get it to compile, it will crash with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on your line of code, but OP hasn't gotten that far!

Comment: Use getIntent().getExtras() ...

Comment: i Suggest to use ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with Java 8. You probably need to do something like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Parcelable parcelable[] = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.PLAYER_KEY);
```

Now, when you use it, you need to cast it to its proper type. Something like this:

```
Player player = (Player)parcelable[0];
```

Comment: fyi, my Java is Java9. But it works! Thank you so much! You are my life saver hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

Implements

> Parcalable

interface with

> Player

class
I used

> Android Parcelable code generator plugin

to do this task.
then you will be able to save your custom objects array in intents.

Answer (score 0):

I use to do something like this

> public void moveToNext(ArrayList images){
>
> ```
>     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
> ```
>
> //add data to parcalable
>
> ```
>     mainIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data",images);
>
>
>     startActivity(mainIntent);
>     finish();
> }
> ```

//while getting data

> ArrayList v =
> getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");